# Use an anchor tag in url after load with knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am working on a knockout page and I have a list of items. For each item I need them to have an anchor tag to scroll to. The problem I'm having is the anchor tag is being loaded from knockout bindings so, when you click on the url from an external page you would have a problem with it actually scrolling to the item. The page with the hash is a separate page. So in you can't scroll to the hash on page load simply because it doesn't exist until knockout loads the bindings.

For example...

My url = `mysite.com/page1#thisItem`

It should link to page1 with an anchor tag like...

```
<a name="thisItem"></a>
```

The problem is that the name gets added after the knockout bindings. I would prefer to do this without javascript checking if it has an id to link to and changing the window.location, however if that's my only choice then I will do it. Does anyone have a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: how are you trying it now? can we see some code showing what you've tried?

Comment: I haven't written it yet because I just don't like the way that I want to write it, which is after page load check url for hashtag ids and then change the window.location to `mysite.com/page1#thisItem`. I'm asking for suggestions on a better solution, maybe there is something someone else knows about knockout that will make it scroll to the id after the page loads without having to check the current url. If you know of any documents that would help let me know. I would rather not have to do it the way I described if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you usecase is simple enough, you could simply check for the target onload, after your KO has initialized, and then just send the user there. Using something like [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) should work:

```
if (location.hash) {
    document.scrollIntoView(document.getElementByName(location.hash)[0]);
}
```

(not tested, adjust for syntax errors, etc!)

Comment: This works perfectly. It's more elegant than I had in mind, but I still wish knockout had something for this already. I already has scroll to in my solution which works like this. but I had to change make the location.hash replace the hash because it keeps the hash when you call it. `location.hash.replace("#", "")`

Answer (score 1):

This example I put together works just fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/915jss01/1/

You need to use the `attr` data-binding to set the anchor target after loading:

```
<a data-bind="attr: {href: '#' + $data}, text: $data"></a>
```

and then similarly to set the target anchor name:

```
<a data-bind="attr: {name: $data}, text: $data"></a>
```

Comment: this is currently what I have. I'm going to adjust my question because now I see where i wasn't clear. The page with the hash is a separate page. So in you can't scroll to the hash on load.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is re-set `window.location.hash` after your page has been set up, and it will scroll there. You have to clear its value before re-assigning it, to get it to recognize the assignment as a change.

I put in a time delay, as the setup was quick enough that the initial setting of the hash "worked".

```js
window.location.hash = '#3'; // because I'm in a snippet
var vm = {
  divs: ko.observableArray([{
    id: '1',
    classname: 'green'
  }, {
    id: '2',
    classname: 'blue'
  }, {
    id: '3',
    classname: 'red'
  }]),
  hashchange: ko.observable(false)
};


setTimeout(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  window.location.hash = '';
  window.location.hash = hash;
}, 100);
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 500px;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: divs">
  <div data-bind="attr: {id: id}, css: classname, text: id">

  </div>
</div>
```